# Android how to get single record from firebase-realtime-database and show into FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I retrieve All data from firebase-realtime-database using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` successfully and I want to show the only child which `bloodGroup = A or B` which selected using `RadioGroup` to select the bloodGroup and show that data into `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` it looks like a search using RadioGroup this is All code I stuck.

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Donator,DonatorViewHolder>adapter;
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.search_recycleView);
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("bloodDonator");
mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
final RadioGroup radioGroupButtonBloodGroup  = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonBloodGroup);
        final RadioButton checkedRadioButton  = radioGroupButtonBloodGroup.findViewById(radioGroupButtonBloodGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        radioGroupButtonBloodGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton checkedRadioButton  = radioGroupButtonBloodGroup.findViewById(checkedId);
                boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
                String bloodGroup = "";
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    switch(checkedId)
                    {
                        case R.id.group_blood_a:
                            bloodGroup = "A";
                            break;
                        case R.id.group_blood_b:
                            bloodGroup = "B";
                            break;
                        case R.id.group_blood_ab:
                            bloodGroup = "AB";
                            break;
                        case R.id.group_blood_o:
                            bloodGroup = "O";
                            break;
                    }
                    final Query querySingle = mDatabase.orderByChild("bloodGroup").equalTo(bloodGroup);// get single record from database
                    querySingle.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                final String address = (String) dataSnapshot1.child("address").getValue();
                                final String bloodGroup = (String) dataSnapshot1.child("bloodGroup").getValue();
                                final String firstname = (String) dataSnapshot1.child("firstname").getValue();
                                String lastname = (String) dataSnapshot1.child("lastname").getValue();
                                String phone = (String) dataSnapshot1.child("phone").getValue();
                                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Donator> options =
                                        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Donator>()
                                                .setQuery(querySingle, Donator.class)
                                                .build();

                                adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Donator, DonatorViewHolder>(options) {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DonatorViewHolder viewHolder, int i, @NonNull Donator donator) {
                                        viewHolder.setAddress(address);//set value to address
                                        viewHolder.setBloodGroup(bloodGroup);// set value to bloodGroup
                                        viewHolder.setFirstname(firstname);// set value to first name
                                    }

                                    @NonNull
                                    @Override
                                    public DonatorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                                .inflate(R.layout.search_card_adapter, parent, false);

                                        return new DonatorViewHolder(view);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChanged() {
                                        super.onDataChanged();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    }
                                };
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Data Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```